# Duplicate a leaflet div (a div that contains also a heatmap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, heatmap

I am having trouble duplicating a div container of a leaflet. I used the clone of jquery to duplicate div over a second one. It works very well for the tailes, but the map has a heatmap layer on it. And this layer the clone ignores completly!

Let me try to put it with a simple example, consider I have two divs, one with the map and other empty!

```html
<button id="duplicateBtn">Duplicate map</button>
   
   <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>
   <p>Next</p>
   <div id="newTestMap" style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>
```

```js
<script> 
        // Treats duplicate button click
       $("#duplicateBtn").click(function(){
            $('#map').clone().appendTo('#newTestMap');
 });
</script>
```

You can find this code at codepen:
http://codepen.io/danielcamara/pen/mAJAQy

However, my real problem is that I want to print the map content with a specific page format. For the map, the user can handle it e.g. change the heat map, add other layers etc... However, when the user decides to print it, I need to print the present status of the map. My idea was to copy the div over another window (the map with all the layers, heatmap and so one), for formatting purposes, before printing with a simple window.print().

I found other printing solutions, e.g. jQuery.print.js, but these do not properly handle the heatmap either.

Does any one has a good solution to either clone the map div or even print it correctly? All suggestions are welcome :)

Daniel